# Change "Add to Cart" Button Text Of Widget Magento 2.3.3

Tags: overrides, magento2.3.3, widget

I want to change button text **"Add To Cart"** To **"Some Text"** With Custom Condition For Widget... **Using Custom Module**

[image]

**Create widget :-**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override your grid.phtml file in your theme

`app/design/frontend/VendorName/ThemeName/Magento_CatalogWidget/templates/product/widget/content/grid.phtml`

and change from

```
<button type="submit"
        title="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Cart')) ?>"
        class="action tocart primary">
    <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Cart')) ?></span>
</button>
```

with your condition to

```
<button type="submit"
        title="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Bag')) ?>"
        class="action tocart primary">
    <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Bag')) ?></span>
</button>
```

Comment: using custom module.

Comment: Here is already answered. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/130437/how-to-extend-catalog-widget-block